# How can I make a line mask which is not parallel to xy-axis on numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((10,10))
startx = 1
starty = 1
endx = 7
endy = 8
```

how can I mask line `(startx, starty) -> (endx, endy)` with width `3` on array `a` ? Any efficient way?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and try to clarify tour question accordingly.  Right now it is too broad and unclear to answer well.  Especially what your expected outcome is.

Comment: Do you mean like plotting, or are you interested in having `1`s in a sort of connected way within your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: `pymrt.geometry` has been removed in favor of [`raster_geometry`](https://pypi.org/project/raster-geometry/).

---

If I understood your question correctly, you want a binary mask that follow a line of any kind in your array.

These kind of problems are usually solved using the [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) or a variation thereof.
The base algorithm is well-known and there is little point in presenting / re-implementing it here once again.

Anyway, an n-dimensional efficient version of this algorithm can be found in `pymrt.geometry.bresenham_line()`, which can be used like:

```
import numpy as np
import pymrt as mrt
import pymrt.geometry

point_a = (1, 1)
point_b = (7, 8)
line_points = tuple(x for x in mrt.geometry.bresenham_line(point_a, point_b))

arr = np.zeros((10, 10))

for line_point in line_points:
    arr[line_point] = 1

print(arr)
# [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Disclaimer: I am the main author of PyMRT.

## EDIT

Alternatively, you could consider the [`bresenham`](https://pypi.org/project/bresenham/) Python package, which is an efficient 2D implementation.